# Try block gives output even when exception is raised by the last command (but not the first)

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I use try/except to catch problems when reading a file line-by-line. The try block contains a series of manipulations, the last of which is usually the cause of the exception. Surprisingly, I noticed that all previous manipulations are executed within the try block even when an exception is raised. This is a problem when trying to turn the dictionary I created to a data frame, because the length of the lists is unequal.

This code creates the problem:

```
d = {'dates':[],'states':[], 'longitude':[], 'latitude':[], 'tweet_ids':[], 'user_ids':[], 'source':[]}
for file in f:
    print("Processing file "+file)
    t1 = file.split('/')[-1].split("_")
    date = t1[0]
    state_code = t1[1]
    state = list(states_ref.loc[states_ref.code==state_code]['abbr'])[0]

    collection = JsonCollection(file)
    counter = 0
    for tweet in collection.get_iterator():
        counter += 1
        try:

            d['dates'].append(date)
            d['states'].append(state)
            t2 = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('geo', tweet)
            if t2 == None:
                d['longitude'].append(t2)
                d['latitude'].append(t2)
            else:
                d['longitude'].append(t2['coordinates'][1])
                d['latitude'].append(t2['coordinates'][0])


#note: the 3 lines bellow are the ones that can raise an exception 
            temp = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('source', tweet)
            t5 =  re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', temp)[0]
            d['source'].append(t5)

        except:
            c += 1
            print("Tweet {} in file {} had a problem and got skipped".format(counter, file))
            print("This is a total  of {} tweets I am missing from the {} archive I process.".format(c, sys.argv[1]))
            next

tab = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

I have fixed the problem by moving the manipulation that is prone to giving the error at the top, but I would like to better understand why try/except is behaving like this. Any ideas?

This code works:

```
d = {'dates':[],'states':[], 'longitude':[], 'latitude':[], 'tweet_ids':[], 'user_ids':[], 'source':[]}
for file in f:
    print("Processing file "+file)
    t1 = file.split('/')[-1].split("_")
    date = t1[0]
    state_code = t1[1]
    state = list(states_ref.loc[states_ref.code==state_code]['abbr'])[0]

    collection = JsonCollection(file)
    counter = 0
    for tweet in collection.get_iterator():
        counter += 1
        try:
            #note: the 3 lines bellow are the ones that can raise an exception 
temp = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('source', tweet)
            t5 =  re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', temp)[0]
            d['source'].append(t5)

            d['dates'].append(date)
            d['states'].append(state)
            t2 = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('geo', tweet)
            if t2 == None:
                d['longitude'].append(t2)
                d['latitude'].append(t2)
            else:
                d['longitude'].append(t2['coordinates'][1])
                d['latitude'].append(t2['coordinates'][0])
        except:
            c += 1
            print("Tweet {} in file {} had a problem and got skipped".format(counter, file))
            print("This is a total  of {} tweets I am missing from the {} archive I process.".format(c, sys.argv[1]))
            next

tab = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you're expecting the effects of previously run statements to be reversed if a exception is thrown?

Comment: a try/except block is not like a database transaction.  if an operation succeeds, it succeeds -- there is no rollback.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. So, what is the best approach for raising an exception when any of the steps is tried? A separate try/except block for each? Is there something more "elegant" to do this?

Comment: @rodonikiAthanasiadou Only code that will throw should be in the block ideally, and, you really should specify what exact exception you want to catch. Blindly catching all exceptions is almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate. The reason I am doing it this way is because some lines in my files are behaving unexpectedly and I have a very big volume of data so I don't mind throwing away a handful, whithout deeply troubleshooting the error (I keep an eye on the volume of data dismissed) .

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a temporal object to hold the output of your functions before appending to the target object. That way if something fails, it will raise an exception before putting data into the target object.

```
try:
    #Put all data into a temporal Dictionary
    #Can raise an exception here
    temp = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('source', tweet)
    t2 = tweet_parser.get_entity_field('geo', tweet)
    tempDictionary = {
        "source"    : re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', temp)[0],
        "latitude"  : None if (t2 is None) else t2['coordinates'][1],
        "longitude" : None if (t2 is None) else t2['coordinates'][0]
    }
    #Append data from temporal Dictionary
    d['source'].append(tempDictionary['source'])
    d['latitude'].append(tempDictionary['latitude'])
    d['longitude'].append(tempDictionary['longitude'])
    d['dates'].append(date)
    d['states'].append(state)
except:
    c += 1
    print("Tweet {} in file {} had a problem and got skipped".format(counter, file))
    print("This is a total  of {} tweets I am missing from the {} archive I process.".format(c, sys.argv[1]))
```